# How to remove Snackbar when navigating to another view

Tags: flutter, dart, snackbar

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _showFlushbar();
  }

  _showFlushbar() async {
    await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 500));
    defaultFlushbar(
      context: context,
      message:
          'Success',
      padding: 50.0,
    );
  }
```

When I navigate to screen, it shows me Flushbar as I expected. But since it have Future.delayed duration, I can't remove it when navigating to another view. How I can remove it without changing duration.

**Thanks**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in flutter `initState`

> Called when this object is inserted into the tree.The framework will call this method exactly once for each State object it creates.

hence your `_showFlushbar` is only called once when you create object. Unless you're refrencing it elsewhere it should only be displayed once.

Due to the delay,it will display later after widget was created

you can always dispose

```
@override
  void dispose() {
    FlashHelper.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
```

Comment: thanks, I forgot about dispose(). Good luck!